# Setting the base-href & context-path in spring-boot - Angular 6 application

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I am building a web application where the UI/client side component is built using Angular 6 and the back end (server-side) is on Spring boot.

Application is expected to be available at

```
http://localhost:8080/FUtility/
```

I set the base-href for angular application by adding the following in appmodule -> providers[]

```
providers: [AuthGuardService, {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/FUtility/'}],
```

At the same time context-root is set in spring-boot by adding the following in application.properties.

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/FUtility
```

But when i try to access the application in the expected path, an empty page is displayed. This is what you see on the debug console.

```
6localhost/:26 GET http://localhost:8080/runtime.js 404 ()
```

> **Note:** Application works fine if I don't set these values.

Is there any procedures that needs to be followed while developing a spring-boot -angular application with "**base-href**"/"**context-path**"?

Development reference: https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/

Comment: Can you just set server.servlet.context-path=/FUtility, do not set from angular side if they are not running as different app

Comment: @kj007 that did not worked... Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
polyfills.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
styles.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
scripts.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
vendor.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Can you please show me your project structure and where you placed all static resources

Comment: I am sorry. I cannot post it due to corporate security issues. But I am following this (https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/) link for development.

Comment: I resolved that issue. but I am not confident enough to post it as an answer, because i dont have a clear explanation for this solution. All i did is to have a <base href="/FUtility/"> in index.html and 'server.servlet.contextPath=/FUtility' in spring boot's application.properties. Along with that I also kept this request handler method to deal with browser refresh.     @RequestMapping(value = "/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}")  
    public String forward2(HttpServletRequest request) {
     System.out.println("---------------------->   "+ request.getRequestURI());
        return "forward:/";
    }